# How to Delete rows in table using Variable in SQL

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jdbc

How should I delete a row using a java variable in SQL table?

I am trying to delete a record from table `member` (with two columns, `name` and `year`) using what the user has input (variable `newName` and `newYear`). I want to find the row that has the same record as what the user has input `(name = newName && year=newYear)` and delete it. However, this code doesn't change anything on the table (no row is deleted although what I have input is correct). What's wrong with my code?

---

```
String newName = memName.getText();

int newYear = parseInt(memYear.getText());
```

are the variables used in the code below.

```
   try {
        s = c.createStatement();
        t = "DELETE FROM member " +
            "WHERE (name='" + newName + "'&& year='" + newYear + "')";
        s.executeUpdate(t);
        s.close();
        c.commit();
        c.close();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AddMember.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saved.");

     memName.setText(null);
     memYear.setText(null);
```

I want the row with the info the user input to be deleted from the table, but it didn't make any changes to my table.

Comment: Do not build your SQL statements like that, you are wide open to SQL injection. Use parameterized queries instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the problem you have is that in SQL you cannot use `&&` instead use `AND` as shown in the following code:

```
t = "DELETE FROM member " +
        "WHERE (name='" + newName + "' AND year='" + newYear + "')";
```